# physijs_worker.js not correctly using Ammo.js constructors? "TypeError: Ammo.btTransform is not a constructor"

Tags: three.js, physics, ammo.js

I've been trying to get Physi.js to work in a simple offline project, and while all the required scripts (Three.js, physi.js, physijs_worker.js, Ammo.js) load and recognize each other, it seems like physijs_worker.js isn't finding/using some of Ammo.js's constructors correctly. Here are the errors I get when I run my code:

[physijs_worker errors (png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sBnO.png)

Here are all the relevant (to my knowledge) bits of my code as well:

In HTML:

```
<script src="lib/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/physi.js"></script>
```

In Javascript:

```
'use strict';

Physijs.scripts.worker = 'lib/physijs_worker.js';
Physijs.scripts.ammo = 'ammo.js';
```

I've fiddled with physijs_worker to try to solve it myself, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Ammo.js certainly has the constructors physijs_worker.js is trying to use, and they are both loading correctly.

Quick edit - In case it's relevant, here are the sources of all of the libraries I'm using:

Three.js - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Physi.js - https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs

The copy of Ammo.js I'm using is from the Physijs repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I managed to solve it by using the `ammo.js` file found under the [examples folder](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/tree/master/examples/js) of Physijs rather than the one at ammo.js repository.